# replace multiple $ sign using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am not able to replace multiple `$` signs using JavaScript/jQuery , 
my JavaScript replace code are as per bellow,

```
var str = $('#amt').html().replace("/\$/g","₹");
alert(str);
```

but it does not replace all occurrence,  Please help me to replace `$` by `₹` symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex is correct, but when wrapped it in quotes, it is no longer a RegEx, it's a **string**.

```
.replace(/\$/g, "₹");
```

And the HTML is not replaced it is just creating a string variable, use

```
$('#amt').html(function (i, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/\$/g, "₹");
});
```

```js
$('#amt').html(function(i, oldHtml) {
  return oldHtml.replace(/\$/g, "₹");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="amt">
  <div>Books: $150.00</div>
  <div>Food: $2050.00</div>
  <div>Total: $2200.00</div>
</div>
```